# Unable to install R package

Tags: r, package, installation

When I tried to install the package coxphf, the following error appeared.
Please let me know how to solve this:

```
install.packages("coxphf")

> Installing package into ‘C:/Users/User/R/win-library/3.4’  
> (as ‘lib’ is unspecified)  
> trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/contrib/3.4/coxphf_1.12.zip'  
Warning in install.packages :  
  cannot open URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/contrib/3.4/coxphf_1.12.zip': HTTP status was '404 Not Found'  
Error in download.file(url, destfile, method, mode = "wb", ...) :   
  cannot open URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/contrib/3.4/coxphf_1.12.zip'  
Warning in install.packages :
  download of package ‘coxphf’ failed
```

Comment: Error is understandable. All the links you have provided returns 404 errors.

Comment: If @Usernamenotfound 's answer below solved your problem, please mark it as the correct answer :)  You might also upvote it. It was very nice of him/her to dig around and find a working link to the package for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like the package isn't available on CRAN at that address.
After digging around, I found the package here: https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/contrib/3.4/coxphf_1.13.zip

Download it and follow instructions here:

http://stat.columbia.edu/~gelman/bugsR/alternate_install.html

It's not expected behavior though, I'm not sure what's causing it, but this workaround will do fine for now

Comment: Thank you for your rapid reply. I wonder there is some relation between coxphf revised only March 3. 2018.

Comment: I can download it, and put download file into R/library/ . It goes well. Thank you very much!!